# Delete list element from a confirmation popup

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a list with delete button for each element , when the user click on the delete button a confirmation dialog appear ,if the user press the OK button i want to delete the list element my problem is how to get the `<li>` list element index in order to remove it from the list , my code not return the correct index , please help me ..

```
  <div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="content">

     <ul data-role="listview" id="employeesList" data-inset="true" data-split-      icon="delete"> 

     <li><a href="#">
    <font class="line1" > Emp1Name</font>
    <font class="line2" >Emp1Salary</font>
    </a><a href="#DeleteConfirm"  data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-                  transition="pop" >Delete</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">
    <font class="line1" > Emp2Name</font>
    <font class="line2" >Emp2Salary</font>
    </a><a href="#DeleteConfirm"  data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-                     transition="pop">Delete</a></li>
     </ul>

  <div data-role="popup" id="DeleteConfirm" data-overlay-theme="a" data-theme="c" data-dismissible="false" style="width:400px;height:200px;" class="ui-corner-all">

  <div  data-theme="c"   style="text-align:center;float:center;height:53px;padding-top:13px;" >
    <font size="6px"  >Delete</font>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" data-theme="d" class="ui-corner-bottom ui-content">
    <font  size="5px" >Do you want to delete this Employee?</font>
    <BR>
   <div style="text-align:center;font-size: 22px;"  >
     <input   type="button" id="No"  data-inline="true" data-icon="delete"  data-theme="c"  value="No " />
     <input   type="button" id="Yes"data-inline="true" data-icon="check"  data-  theme="c"   value=" Yes" data-corners="false"/> 
</div>

    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Java script code:

```
   var SelectedLi ;
   $('#DeleteConfirm').on('click',function(){

        SelectedLi= $(this).parent().index();
    });

    $('#Yes').on('click',function(){

         $('#employeesList').remove(SelectedLi);
         $('#DeleteConfirm').popup('close');
    });


    $('#No').on('click' ,function(){

         $('#DeleteConfirm').popup('close');
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I do my popup:

HTML:

```
<div data-role="popup" id="sterge"  data-overlay-theme="a" data-theme="c" data-dismissible="false" style="max-width:400px;" class="ui-corner-all">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" class="ui-corner-top">
                <h1>Delete?</h1>
            </div>
         <div data-role="content" data-theme="d" class="ui-corner-bottom ui-content">
                <h3 class="ui-title">To Delete Product from Bonus?</h3>
                <p>This action cannot be undone.</p>
               <input id="giveupButton" data-inline="true"   type="button" value="Cancel"/>
               <input id="delButton" data-inline="true" onclick="deletebonusproduct();" data-theme="b"  type="button" value="Delete"/>
            </div>
        </div>
```

JS:

```
    $(document.body).on('click', '.del' ,function(){
    li = $(this).parent();
    $('#sterge').popup("open"); 
    });

    $(document.body).on('click', '#delButton' ,function(){
    $('#sterge').popup("close");

    li.remove();
    });

    $(document.body).on('click', '#giveupButton' ,function(){
    $('#sterge').popup("close");
    });
```

Comment: thank you very much for helping me its worked , but the event trigger two times i have tried to use delegate, unbind-bind but the event still triggering two times how can i solve this issue ??

Comment: I put it the JS in my pagebeforeshow where I want my popup to fire. For example:$(document).on("pagebeforeshow","#pricing",function()... It fires only once for me.

Answer (score 2):

You have mistake in binding event to *split button*, it should be as follows:

```
var SelectedLi ='' ;

$('[href=#DeleteConfirm]').on('click',function (e) {
   // store parent of clicked button
    SelectedLi = $(this).closest("li");
});

$('#Yes').on('click',function(){
  $(SelectedLi).remove();
  $('#employeesList').listview("refresh");
  $('#DeleteConfirm').popup('close');
});


$('#No').on('click' ,function(){
  $('#DeleteConfirm').popup('close');
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/Vvhh3/)**

Comment: thanks for helping me , but it didn't work  on the emulator  when i tried it !! " i am working for android platform " the element not removed

Comment: @user are you getting any error? Are sure you have used my code as is? Because you had a selector mistake.

Comment: I have used your code as it is , there is no error, the click event on $('[href=#DeleteConfirm]') not fired since i put an alert before this statement  SelectedLi = $(this).closest("li"); and the alert didn't appear

Comment: @user wrap the code inside `$(document).on("pageinit", "#page_id", function () { // code above });`.

Comment: the problem still ,the event not fired , but when i use$('#DeleteConfirm') the event work on the emulator but the returned li index is wrong

Comment: @user give split buttons a class i.e. `DeleteBtn` and use as a selector instead `[href=#DeleteConfirmation]`.

Comment: not worked also , the only working way is the use of $('#DeleteConfirm') but the returned index when i select the first element in the list is -1 not 0 , is there another way to get the index of li ???

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43079/discussion-between-omar-and-user)